# Issues with deploying a Rails app in a subdomain (Apache and Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, subdomain, virtualhost

For the backstory, I had to reinstall my server, so I did a backup of the few websites that were here and I'm currently redploying them. However, one of them is the english version of one of the websites I already deployed.

However, when I reinstalled the server, I forgot to do a backup of the configuration files, because I remembered that it wasn't this difficult to set up the last time I did it, but, heh, here am I.

so here is the configuration file of the english version:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias en.mywebsite.fr
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite-en/public
    RailsEnv development
    PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.3/ruby
    SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/mywebsite-en/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to `en.mywebsite.fr`, it "works" but I'm actually in the french part of the website.

Here is the list of things I tried to do (while reloading apache each time), but didn't work:

- ServerAlias en.mywebsite.fr
- ServerName en.mywebsite.fr
- ServerName website.fr en.website.fr
- ServerAlias website.fr en.website.fr

**Edit: Here how the main website looks like**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.fr
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.fr
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/public
    RailsEnv development
    PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.3/ruby
    SetEnv GEM_HOME /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/home/mywebsite/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What other VHost files are there? Do any of them take over `*.website.fr`?

Comment: There are 2 others of them, one is not concerned and the other is the "main" website, not the english translation. I'm updating the question (and no, no other subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

If content is being server from main site, then most likely there is a wild card entry `*.mywebsite.fr`. Can you try `random.mywebsite.fr`. It would confirm existence of wild card entry.

Also, try changing `ServerAlias` to `ServerName` for your `en` config.

Comment: Ok so there is a weird behaviour that I can't explain: I changed 'en' by 'random' then restarted apache, however 'en' is still accepted while 'random' isn't, and I don't have a single clue why.

Comment: random is not accessible bcoz probably no IP is mapped to it

Comment: True, now that you say it, I defined the redirection within the domain name, so it can't be anything else

Comment: another way to test it would be to remove your main vhost file, restart and try en.mywebsite

Comment: also have you removed ServerAlias and put ServerName?

Comment: Ok so I found out that I forgot to run the command `a2ensite` after recreating the config file. I'm mad at myself but at least it works now... Thank you for trying to help me!